# Changing chapter style in KOMA package

Tags: chapters, koma-script

This is my minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[headinclude=true,twoside=true,BCOR=5mm,fontsize=11pt,paper=17cm:24cm,pagesize,DIV=13,headings=normal,appendixprefix=true,numbers=noendperiod,toc=bibliography,parskip=false,captions=bottombeside,version=last]{scrbook}

\DeclareOldFontCommand{\bf}{\normalfont\bfseries}{\mathbf}
\addtokomafont{caption}{\small}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[separate-uncertainty=true,multi-part-units=single]{siunitx}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.markings,positioning,fadings,calc}
\newcommand{\onlyinsubfile}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\notinsubfile}[1]{}
\newcommand*\chem[1]{\ensuremath{\mathrm{#1}}}
\newcommand{\vcenteredinclude}[2]{\begingroup
\setbox0=\hbox{\includegraphics[width=#1]{#2}}%
\parbox{\wd0}{\box0}\endgroup}
\newcommand{\specialcell}[2][c]{%
  \begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}c@{}}#2\end{tabular}}
\usepackage[toc]{appendix}
\renewcommand{\onlyinsubfile}[1]{}
\renewcommand{\notinsubfile}[1]{#1}
\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalcolor\bfseries}


\begin{document}

\subfile{../Chapter_Introduction/Chapter_Introduction}

\end{document}
```

[I realize this is not a real MWE but I got some errors after deleting most of the commands, so I just kept them here now.]

Which produces the chapter title:

[image].

Upon using this code (from a question on Stack Exchange, can't find the thread anymore)

```
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
  \thechapter\enskip
  \textcolor{gray!50}{\rule[-\dp\strutbox]{2pt}{\baselineskip}}\enskip
}
```

the Chapter title becomes:

[image].

I have two questions:

1) How can I change the comment such that the second image has the same font as the first?

2) Is it possible to make the Chapter Number and the bar bigger? I naively tried commands like `\bigg' but it did not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Remove `\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalcolor\bfseries}` from your preamble to use a sansserif font for the chapters.
2. You could add a fontsize command to the redefinition of `\chapterformat`.

Example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{tikz}% loads also graphicx,xcolor, etc.

%\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalcolor\bfseries}

\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{{%
  \Huge\thechapter\enskip
  \textcolor{gray!50}{\rule[-\dp\strutbox]{4pt}{\baselineskip}}\enskip
}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

---

**Update** (because of a comment below this answer)

To change the size of the chapter title too, use `\addtokomafont{chapter}{<fontsize command>}`.

The height of the gray rule can be changed in its third (=second mandantory) argument. If you want to change the horizontal position of the rule, adjust the first (optional) argument.

Example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{{%
  \Huge\thechapter\enskip
  \textcolor{gray!50}{\rule[-2.5\dp\strutbox]{4pt}{2\baselineskip}}\enskip
}}

\addtokomafont{chapter}{\small}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

Comment: But tikz might slow down compilation much more than graphicx and xcolor.

Comment: @KeksDose Yes: "etc." means the other packages ;-) and the OP already loads `tikz`  in his/her example code.

Comment: @esdd I played a bit with your suggestion. Is it also possible to change the standard font size of the chapter title within the same \renewcommand? Because now I have a chapter number which is quite big so I would like the chapter title to be a bit bigger as well.

Comment: Should both the number and the title use the same fontsize?

Comment: @esdd No, I would rather change them separately... Related: how can I make the gray bar higher?

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: @esdd Related question: for my thesis I have a separate file called "covermatter.tex" with the title of my thesis. I import it into the main thesis file before I call \fontmatter. The title is now not displayed in the same style as the chapter headers (I think you called it sansserif), but rather in the font of the second image I put in my post (the standard font). Do you know how to locally change my covermatter such that it has the same sansserif style?

Comment: It dependence a bit on the code in your `covermatter.tex`. You could use `\sffamily` inside a group, eg. the `titlepage` environment. But maybe you want to use `\usekomafont{disposition}`.